# Checking unwanted characters in input box by array ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys am trying to use array method .keeping all the unwanted characters in array and checking one by one.

My code:-

html:-

```
Username:<input type="text" class="my">
 output: <span class="out">output</span>
```

js:-

```
 $(".my").keydown(function(){
 var Ii = $.trim($(this).val());
  if (Ii.indexOf('>') == -1 && Ii.indexOf('<') == -1 && Ii.indexOf('+') == -1 && Ii.indexOf('@') == -1 && Ii.indexOf('!') == -1) { 
      $('.out').text(Ii);
  }else{
    $('.out').text('sorry you cannot input this');
  }
  });
```

I know this is totally wrong so Please give your logic using array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keypress event and event preventDefault.

```js
$(".my").on('keypress', function(e) {
    var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if ('><+@!'.indexOf(c) == -1) {
        $('.out').empty();
    }else{
        $('.out').text('sorry you cannot input this: ' + c);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


Username:<input type="text" class="my">
output: <span class="out">output</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work, use `.split("")` to split the string into an array.

```js
$(".my").keyup(function() {
  var Ii = $.trim($(this).val()).split("");
  if (Ii.indexOf('>') == -1 && Ii.indexOf('<') == -1 && Ii.indexOf('+') == -1 && Ii.indexOf('@') == -1 && Ii.indexOf('!') == -1) {
    $('.out').text($(this).val());
  } else {
    $('.out').text('sorry you cannot input this: '+Ii[Ii.length - 1]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Username:
<input type="text" class="my"> output: <span class="out">output</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
$.inArray( your_input_text, [ ">", "<", "+", "@" ] );